# How do I debug an API call (fetch request)?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm using react and trying to fetch data from this API
https://6033c4d8843b15001793194e.mockapi.io/api/locations

I want to get the name, but it is not loading anything. How do i debug that and see what part of my code is working and what isn't?

```
function Card() {
    const url = "https://6033c4d8843b15001793194e.mockapi.io/api/locations";
    const [locations, setLocations] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            setLocations(response.data)
        })

    }, [url])

    if(locations) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Acme HQ</h1>
                <p>{locations.id}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>error</h1>
        </div>
    )

   
}
```

This is my code, it doesn't throw any error but it also doesn't output anything.

I want to retrieve the name or the usercount from that API

Answer (score 3):

Because the api return an array of object. So you can get an id of item in the array like this:

```
{locations?.[0].id}
```

To render items from array. You can using `map`: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Holy crap, that worked!

I have all of that data, I want to create an HTML card for as many elements as there are ids and with the data of each one (they are 20 for now). WHat would you suggest?

Comment: You can using map to render all element

Comment: Thank you for your input @Viet I'm not that familiar with that, but I am kind of following what you are saying. Is there a chance where you could maybe tell me what to google so I can accomplish that?

I have those 20 items (20 ids per say), I would like to create a new card for each one and for them to update based on the API data, so if the data changes they'd change too.